# Dreamweaver highlight all selected

Tags: editor, dreamweaver

Is there a way to make DW highlight all selected word like in notepad++ ? Comes very handy when working with variables.

[image: word highlight]

Comment: I don't think so.  Dreamweaver doesn't have as good of an intellisense as Notepadd++ (which is still not "good enough" for me when doing anything involving more than two custom class objects).